# Carlo Rovelli, Order of Time, time and events

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time

Rovelli says that "the fundamental equations do not include a time variable".
Further, the world is made of events.
It seems to me that events are intrinsically temporal. A kiss has a duration. How can he reconcile this?

Comment: Which fundamental equations?

Comment: can you give a link?

Comment: If they do not include the time variable they also not include the space variables. The situation seems   quite symmetric to me...Maybe he is referring to pure quantum gravity where the Hamiltonian vanishes (it is a constraint of the theory) and thus there is no time evolution.

Comment: Yeah basically... I recall seeing a talk from Carlo where I think the “fundamental equation” in question was the Wheeler-DeWitt equation. The point seemed to be that the world was one really big Feynman-diagram-like graph, where the “events” are vertices  and the “length” of the edges was somehow not well-defined so had to be reconstructed from the graph. Or something. I might be mixing up unrelated talks from different people.

Comment: Read about Wheeler-DeWitt equation and Page-Wooters mechanism.
And then read this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4691

Comment: Note that a kiss is made up of an infinity of events (luckily, or not...). The event has no duration, even though the time is involved in an event. If you think that the world is made of events, time is involved but the whole of events is stationary (no duration involved). Which doesn't make the kiss (indeed evolving in time for us) feel worse (or better...).

Comment: Yes, the problem is that in the book Rovelli doesn't make a clear distinction between normal events and quantum events. He goes on about things like stones being events. One moment he is talking about macro events, and the next moment he is talking about quantum events.

Comment: To Anna I can't easily give a link. I searched for links myself without good result. That is why I asked the question. You have to read the book

Answer (score 4):

All he is saying is that the laws of physics are not explicitly time dependent. For example, the relationship $E=mc^2$ does not vary with $t$.

Comment: No but the Schroedinger equation does involve time. Rovelli thinks it is a simplification, LIke Newton's ideas.

Comment: No E=mc2  does not vary wih t, c2 is a constant. But surely we cannot think of speed without time.

Comment: Agreed. Clearly one can argue with Rovelli's statement, but its validity depends on what he takes to be the 'fundamental' equations.

Answer (score 4):

I have not read the book you are citing, but I note the use of the phrase 'the fundamental equations'. I think he must be referring to various equations that make up the way physics at the level of space, time and basic constituents of the cosmos is currently formulated. Such equations are 'fundamental' in certain respects, but not in others. For example, they do not constitute the correct description in full, because we do not know what that correct description is. There are many unknowns in physics. He appears to be advancing the hypothesis that the entire story of the cosmos is based on time-reversible basic processes. This is widely thought to be so because quantum mechanics seems to suggest it, but it is not known and there is evidence in the other direction. For example, one of the counter-arguments comes from the physics of black holes and Hawking radiation (the black hole information paradox). Another comes from the long-standing debate over exactly how the maths of quantum physics connects to the story of the physical events themselves (the quantum measurement problem). Another comes from the sensitivity of processes to initial conditions, and the fact that infinitely precise real numbers are a mathematical idealization and it is not clear whether this idealization captures the nature of the physical world precisely, or is just a useful idealization.

So the main aim of this answer is to say that your question goes to what is the nature of the physical world, whether it genuinely develops in new ways or whether its future is encoded in its present. The main aim of my answer is to point out that when people assert with confidence that they 'know' the nature of the physical world to be such that time is like a parameter rather than allowing development of genuine novelty, they do not in fact know this to be true. It is just an interpretive posture, one that downplays the counter-evidence.

I would say that your example of a kiss is a perfectly apt example of something that does indeed happen and gets the status of 'event'; something that can be recognized and whose meaning can be discussed.   Our knowledge of physics is very far from being able to support the conclusion that the decision of two specific people to share a kiss is somehow encoded into the parameters of the universe at the time of the Big Bang.

Comment: As someone has pointed out above, a kiss is made up of quantum events. The problem is that Rovelli moves between macro and micro events in his book. I don't think Rovelli means that a kiss has anything to do with the parameters of the universe at time of the Big Bang. But's that a good question. When does determinism begin?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot find the exact words that you quote in Rovelli's book, but a similar phrase occurs near the beginning of Chapter 6 "The World is Made of Events not Things". Here is the paragraph in full:

> The absence of the quantity 'time' in the fundamental equations does not imply a world that is frozen and immobile. On the contrary, it implies a world in which change is ubiquitous, without being order by Father Time; without innumerable events being necessarily distributed in good order, or along the single Newtonian timeline or according to Einstein's elegant geometry. The events of the world do not form an orderly queue, like the English. They crowd around chaotically, like the Italians.

Rovelli agrees that events have duration. What he disagrees with is the idea that events occur in a fixed sequence - instead, he sees them as forming a complex network. In mathematical terms, this is the difference between a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) and a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

At this point Rovelli has spent the first five chapters of the book showing that our intuitive notion of time as a continuous and independent background to everything in the universe is flawed, and has been demolished successively by thermodynamics, general relativity and quantum mechanics. Later on, in Chapter 8 "Dynamics as Relation" he says

> The fundamental equations of quantum gravity are effectively formulated like this: they do not have a time variable, and they describe the world by indicating the possible relations between variable quantities.

When he says "quantum gravity" he means the particular version of [loop quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity) on which he works. This is one of several possible candidates for a theory of quantum gravity, and it has not yet been experimental verified (or disproved).

Comment: If he agrees that events have a duration then he is introducing time at a fundamental level. He must be speaking specifically of quantum events which we assume have no duration. Assuming this, he  may be right about time.

Comment: So is he saying that time exists with respect to events, but that the relation between events does not have a fixed temporal order?

Comment: Yes, although Rovelli’s “events” are Planck-level quantum events connected together in a network called a “spin network”, and time as we understand it is an emergent property of the network. This is explained more fully in Chapter 8 of the book.

Comment: Glad to know that "events" are Plank-level quantum events. Rovelli, early on in the book, goes on about macroscopic events. For example a stone is an event. True, but it causes confusion about what events are crucial.

Comment: OK, it seems to me that he is arguing that there is no overall time or "Father Time" to these quantum events. Still it seems to me that they must have "local" times. No spin without time. Just because there is no overall time, and arguably one can say this of the whole universe, that doesn't mean there is no time at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are to ways to look at it:

- Hypothesis 1 :

One approach assumes that time is a "thing" per se; a sort of linear dimension, like the 3 dimensions of classical space and that events happen as a function of said parameter.

- Hypothesis 2 :

Another approach assumes that events "just happens" in a given sequence (which we call causality). Under that second hypothesis, time is not a "thing", merely a "currency" or conversion factor, a way to compare the frequency of cyclical phenomena (non-dissipative) to the frequency of another one (the cycle of the days compared to the cycles of the moon for instance (days and months, basically)). Also, the same concept can be used to measure the relative value of dissipative phenomenon compared to cyclical phenomenons in terms of cycles or sub-cycles, etc. (for example, the average human being lives for about 70 years, roughly 700 moon cycles, whereas the average dog will live 7 years (roughly 70 moon cycles, hence a factor of 10)).

Under the second hypothesis, time is not a "thing", not a physical primitive value, but a derived value sometimes called "emergent".

In that sense, it is not real (in the sense: not fundamental); it is just a convenient parameter that can be used to describe, parametrise, the evolution of a dissipative system (in terms of cycles of a non-dissipative system).

Under the second hypothesis, it is not the entropy of an isolated system that grows with time; it is the evolution (in a succession of causal events) of an isolated system that translates into a progressive increase of entropy, which in turn yields the illusion that the system's evolution is driven by the passing of time.

The second approach makes more sense than the first one, because it accounts for the facts that:

- Fondamental physical equations are time-reversible (no microscopic arrow of time).
- Time is not a dimension like space.

Comment: Your hypothesis 2 hits the mark. But I cannot help thinking that time actually is the causal order of events. If it is. then it doesn't need to emerge, it already is.

Comment: There is usually a distinction between time as a dimension, and time as a mere ordering of events.

Comment: Time is not a dimension like space. This seems to go against the idea of space-time being unitary. According to relativity time is the fourth dimension. Or so I understood it to be.

Comment: Yes. I believe currently that spacetime, in the current definition of GR is just a tool, just a convenient (yet accurate) description. According to Sean Carrol, spacetime itself could be "emergent" (not fundamental) in a description based on QM.

Comment: Certain particles have spin. The spin, it seems, must have a speed.

Comment: Is speed ontologically prior to time? There is a passage in his book, which I cannot remember exactly, but he asks us to imagine a scene where there is no reference to time. There are hills, trees, a river, and also, strangely, a fast train. How can there be a fast train without reference to time, unless speed is ontologically prior to time?

Comment: @Marek Perhaps speed might be ontologically prior to time because there is an absolute reference for speed ($c$ according to GR) and moreover, perhaps $c$ also is the speed of causality. My point of vue is that causality translates into sequences of events which complete at different paces (or speed), which in turn we interpret as time.

Comment: Thanks for that. If only Rovelli would make these things clear. This is a big statement "Speed is ontologically prior to time". He should explicitly say so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if and where Rovelli made such a statement, but this statement is wrong because there are fundamental time processes:

The cosmologic process of space expansion is time dependent. And there is also a microcosmic fundamental time-dependent equation which is a bit less common: The spin of mass particles is a physical process which is time dependent, that means, the "revolution" of one spin takes a certain time, and we could define the age of a particle by counting the number of "revolutions" of its spin.

Comment: Rovelli has always maintained in his books (eg. The Order of Time) that time is an emergent property. However, you are probably right in regard to spin. I wonder how he would deal with that objection. After all he is a renowned physicist. The only answer I can think of in my ignorance is that "mass particles" are secondary.

Comment: A universe of massless particles would not generate any proper time, such that the existence of mass particles seems to be essential for the existence of time. The creation of proper time (and - in a second step - the observation of time in the form of coordinate time) is described in the equation of the action of a point particle $$S = mc^2\int{d\tau}:$$ According to this equation, the action of the rest energy $mc^2$ of mass particles seems to consist in the creation of their own aging $\tau$, along their respective worldlines.

Comment: OK, massless particles would not generate proper time. My one remaining problem is how speed is fundamental - and Rovelli seems to see speed as fundamental - can be made sense of without time.

Comment: This would be worth a new question (often, a precise formulation of the question is already half of the answer).

Answer (score -1):

I was wondering about this myself too! I think he just means that the whole of spacetime (including all events and wordlines) is a static entity. This entity is called the [block universe](https://interestingengineering.com/block-universe-theory-is-the-passing-of-time-an-illusion), as you've probably heard of. The *passage* of time is an illusion in this view of the universe. It doesn't exist in reality. Past, present, and future exist all at the same, well..., time. In the *growing* half-block universe only the past and present coexist at the same time, while the future is not (yet) part of this whole.
So, while time and space exist in this view, the passage of time does not.

Because this block universe doesn't change, no time variable is needed to describe it. There simply *is* no time variable. Only instant times exist.